# Ugly AUC curves. Sklearn. How to make AUC Curves less square

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, visualization, matplotlib, auc

I dislike the square look of this AUC curve (SKLearn).

The purpose of this question is "visual". Please post code snippets.

This question is not requesting the theory behind the AUC.

## My goal is to make the curve look like a curve. Right now, the curve looks like a square.

Please refer to the sample code below.

```
precision, recall, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, pos_probs)
plt.plot(precision , recall, marker='.')
plt.show()
```

```
RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(y_test, pos_probs)
```

## The code above produces the below ugly curves.

[image]

## The curve appearance I want to achieve (red line only).

[image]

Comment: You could make up data until you get the curve you want. (That was a joke; don’t do that.) Aside from that, the curve looks how it looks. I’m not following the issue here. Could you please explain and clarify?

Comment: @Dave The red curve is what I want. The blue curve is what I am getting.

Comment: You get what the data support. What’s the problem?

Comment: @Dave Correct. I understand that. Is there a method or are you aware of a method to make the AUC curve less square-ish? For example, adding additional plotting points without altering the final outcome. For example, when you do line charts/histograms in matplotlib, you can use a log method to "soften" (less square) the line appearance.

Comment: For all other viewers, As of this date, there's no known way to soften AUC curves visually without altering the final outcome. If any stackoverflow has a way to make AUC less square in the near future, please feel free to share.

Comment: More data Will give a less square result

Answer (score 1):

As Dave and Thiago are saying in the comments, the shape of the ROC curve  depends on the **data**, especially the number of possible thresholds in the data.

(it's not called AUC curve btw, AUC stands for "Area Under Curve")

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/87363/64377) you can find an explanation about how the ROC curve is defined, which explains why it has a particular shape.

Your curve looks as if there are only 3 points, including the two extremes. You're right that this is not typical.

- Imho the most likely is an error: check the values in `pos_probs`, because apparently they have only a few distinct values. Are these values obtained with `predict` or `predict_proba`? It should be the latter (common mistake, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184906/difference-between-predict-vs-predict-proba-in-scikit-learn) for instance).
- Otherwise it's a matter of too few different points in the data: how many instances do you have? Are the instances diverse enough? If you only have a couple *distinct* instances, then this kind of curve would be normal. If so, making the curve artificially similar to the red line would be a mistake.